# I cant see my data Firebase DB on Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I can see my data on Flutter Databese, but it disappears on the loading screen. It appears and disappears at first, what is the reason, how can I solve this problem ?

When I press the product group, the data appears at first, but then it disappears.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:warehouse_management/models/product.dart';
import 'package:warehouse_management/screens/new_product_page.dart';
import 'package:warehouse_management/screens/search_product_in_group.dart';
import 'package:warehouse_management/utils/color_palette.dart';
import 'package:warehouse_management/widgets/product_card.dart';

class ProductGroupPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? name;
  ProductGroupPage({Key? key, this.name}) : super(key: key);

  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: 10,
          right: 10,
        ),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) {
                  return NewProductPage(
                    group: name,
                  );
                },
              ),
            );
          },
          splashColor: ColorPalette.bondyBlue,
          backgroundColor: ColorPalette.pacificBlue,
          child: const Icon(
            Icons.add,
            color: ColorPalette.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(
        color: ColorPalette.pacificBlue,
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
            color: ColorPalette.aquaHaze,
            height: double.infinity,
            width: double.infinity,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 10,
                    left: 10,
                    right: 15,
                  ),
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: 90,
                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: ColorPalette.pacificBlue,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(16),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.chevron_left_rounded,
                              size: 35,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            },
                          ),
                          Text(
                            name!.length > 14
                                ? '${name!.substring(0, 12)}..'
                                : name!,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: "Nunito",
                              fontSize: 28,
                              color: ColorPalette.timberGreen,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          IconButton(
                            splashColor: ColorPalette.timberGreen,
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.search,
                              color: ColorPalette.timberGreen,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).push(
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (context) =>
                                      SearchProductInGroupPage(
                                    name: name,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: const Icon(
                              Icons.delete,
                              color: ColorPalette.timberGreen,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              //TODO
                            },
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: const [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 20,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          const Text(
                            "Ürünler",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: ColorPalette.timberGreen,
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontFamily: "Nunito",
                            ),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(height: 20),
                          Expanded(
                            child: StreamBuilder(
                              stream: _firestore
                                  .collection("products")
                                  .where("group", isEqualTo: name)
                                  .orderBy('name')
                                  .snapshots(),
                              builder: (
                                BuildContext context,
                                AsyncSnapshot<
                                        QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>
                                    snapshot,
                              ) {
                                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                                  return const Center(
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      height: 40,
                                      width: 40,
                                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }
                                return ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                                  itemBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    return ProductCard(
                                      product: Product.fromMap(
                                        snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
                                      ),
                                      docID: snapshot.data!.docs[index].id,
                                    );
                                  },
                                );
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can also find the fields I created for Firebase in the appendix.

[image: FirebaseCloud]

When I click on the first field on the previous page, my data appears and then disappears.

[image]

Then, after 1 second, my data disappears, it appears on firebase, but not on the screen.

[image]

Comment: How long have you been getting this error? Have you stopped Flutter, then started it back to check? Have you tried using the Firebase emulators? Maybe add an if block for snapshot.hasError and print any errors (add this just before the if block of !snapshot.hasData), let's see if some errors occur

Comment: <meta-data from Manifest.xml
     android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
     android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
I solved the problem by removing the /> code. Thank you so much

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
    android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
/>
```

The solution is to remove the above code.